# pass parameters to webbrowser control during foreach loop does not work

Tags: c#, foreach, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser Control on a C# Windows Form which gets a few parameter. Because of some Ajax Content the webbrowser raise the DocumentCompleted multiple times. In addition to that the webpage where I fill some values in form fields (this is what mean with passing parameters to control) loads not very fast i have a timer which runs every 2 secs to try to fill the values. So far so good but now I have different values which I need to pass to the form and the website needs to be loaded again.
I am having those values in a list which I go through using a foreach loop. The problem is that the foreachloop is too fast so that the webbrowser control only gets the last value of that list.

I hope you guys understand what I mean. Do you have some recommendations/tips/tricks what I should do to fix this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Below is the code of the foreach which triggers the Timer at the end which then goes through the process of loading the page, passing parameters and so on...

```
    foreach (string routeFrom in lstRoutesFrom)
    {
        string routeTo = lstRoutesTo[lstRoutesFrom.IndexOf(routeFrom)].ToString();

        //Prepare Data...
        this.requestAirportFrom = routeFrom;
        this.requestAirportTo = routeTo;

        string dd = "13";
        string mm = "07";
        string yyyy = "2012";
        string date = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;
        this.requestDate = date;

        this.globalStep = 0;
        listAirline.Clear();
        listArrAirports.Clear();
        listArrTime.Clear();
        listDepAirports.Clear();
        listDepTime.Clear();
        listFlightNumbers.Clear();
        listFlightPrices.Clear();
        btnTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: No code, no cookie. Please provide your loop code.

Comment: Thanks! Added the foreach code above...

Answer (score 1):

Your foreach is not 'too fast', it's simply incorrect.

```
foreach (string routeFrom in lstRoutesFrom)  // this gets multiple 'routeFrom' values
{
   //Prepare Data...
   this.requestAirportFrom = routeFrom;  // and now (over)write all to the same place

   ....
}
```

Only the last `routeFrom` is saved in *the* (1) `this.requestAirportFrom` location.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question : *The problem is that the foreachloop is too fast so that the webbrowser control only gets the last value of that list.*

WebBrowser Control have DocumentCompleted Event you can make use of it to pass one item at a time

See example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx)